# How to get all unselected values from SELECT (Multiple) jQuery | JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
 <select id="user-type" multiple="multiple">
        <option value="1">Type-1</option>
        <option value="2">Type-1</option>
        <option value="3">Type-1</option>
    </select>
```

i have this select list Tag have some options with values.I need to put unselected item to array please help !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it like this:

```
$('#user-type').change(function(){
  var uns = $("option:not(:selected)",this).map(function() {
    return this.value
  }).get();
});
```

**Demo**

```js
$('#user-type').change(function(){
  var uns = $("option:not(:selected)",this).map(function() {
    return this.value
  }).get();
  console.log(uns);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="user-type" multiple="multiple">
        <option value="1">Type-1</option>
        <option value="2">Type-1</option>
        <option value="3">Type-1</option>
    </select>
```